# width not working in media print and print problem in firefox browser

Tags: html, css

When I print it looks different in Firefox. I tried it on Chrome and it looks good. The second chart will break into another page. I want it to look like on Chrome.  How to fix it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NWj8.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHU1G.jpg)

i have tried to give this but, it remain same.

```
div.chrt{
        page-break-before: avoid;
    }
```

Also, I want to ask why width does not work in my chart, even if I already style it with this code

```
.chart{
        top: 0 !important;
        width: 72% !important;
    }
```

Comment: Try creating a jsfiddle like this one http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/3xdks0qo/ or this on http://jsfiddle.net/cybentizen/77ftsnvg/  You'll find some good information here as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32089576/firefox-ignores-page-break-before-when-printing

Comment: it still looks like that on firefox